# After exit an app. How to open next activity after timer end count?

Tags: android, android-intent, timer, countdowntimer

I have `CountDownTimer` which is running after I exit an app:

```
 countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftMilis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeLeftMilis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountTextView();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                runnning = false;
                textView.setText("00:00:00");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sound.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }.start();
        runnning = true;
```

onStop and onStart methods:

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences shpref = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shpref.edit();
        editor.putLong(END_TIME,endTime);
        editor.putLong(MILISECOND_START, mTimeStartMilis);
        editor.putLong(MILISECOND_LEFT, timeLeftMilis);
        editor.putBoolean(RUNNING, runnning);   
        editor.apply();
        if(countDownTimer != null){
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        endTime = sharedPreferences.getLong(END_TIME,0);
        mTimeStartMilis = sharedPreferences.getLong(MILISECOND_START, -1);
        timeLeftMilis = sharedPreferences.getLong(MILISECOND_LEFT, -1);
        runnning = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(RUNNING, false);
        if (runnning) {
            timeLeftMilis = endTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (timeLeftMilis < 0) {
                timeLeftMilis = 0;
                runnning = false;
                updateCountTextView();
                updateButtons();
            } else {
                startTimer();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

The problem is when I exit an app and time is end, beacuse method `onFinish()` not start Sound.class
How to start an intent after exit app? Do I have to register `receiver` ?

**EDIT**

My Alarm Class

```
public class Alarm extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.dsh);
            mediaPlayer.start();

    }
    public void onClickOff(View view){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        finishAndRemoveTask();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    public static class Second extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,Alarm.class);
            context.startActivity(intent1);
        }

}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Alarm"/>
        <receiver android:name=".Alarm$Second"/>
```

When I have Activity opened it is working but when exit, it is not working.
I have this code in `onFinish` method.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alarm.Second.class);
                PendingIntent pd = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(),1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis() + 1, pd);
```

Comment: Set alarm manager that calls after 2 to 3 seconds later, before your app exit. Now in broadcast receiver do your stuffs. This will work, let me know if you didn't understand.

Comment: I edit my answer, can you check it, beacuse it is not working. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: where your Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); set 2 seconds after in this calender. And use "am.set" instead of "am. setExact".

Answer (score 0):

you can use handle same as a splash screen if you work with
for eg. a splash screen timer is 2 second then you can call handler for 2 second
a perfect example is below

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,NavigationMenuActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();
            }
        },2500);
```

Comment: Your sollutions doesn't worked for me. Beacuse when I exit app, ``onFinish``` doesn't fire anything.

Comment: after exits app it is not possible to automatically open a new app because the android system did not allow to automatic open new app without any event....can you show it anywhere or if you have an example app then please share me after i will sugggest him

Comment: I edited my main question, so please check it. I registered recevier but not working...